# Sum of dice rolls

Tags: c, multinomial

I am trying to compute the probability of getting a specific sum from *n* rolls of  *s*-sided dice. I found the formula in this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html) (formula 10).

This is the code that I wrote in C:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <math.h>

# define n      2   // number of dices
# define s      6   // number of sides of one dice

int fact(int x){
  int y = 1;
  if(x){
    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
      y *= i;
  }
  return y;
}
int C(int x,int y){
  int z = fact(x)/(fact(y)*fact(x-y));
  return z;
}

int main(){
  int     p,k,kmax;
  double  proba;

  for(p = n; p <= s*n; p++){
    proba = 0.0;
    kmax = (p-n)/s;
    for(k = 0; k <= kmax; k++)
      proba += pow(-1.0,k)*C(n,k)*C(p-s*k-1,p-s*k-n);
    proba /= pow((float)s,n);
    printf("%5d %e\n",p,proba);
  }
}
```

Here are the results for:

Two 6-sided dice:

```
2    2.777778e-02
3    5.555556e-02
4    8.333333e-02
5    1.111111e-01
6    1.388889e-01
7    1.666667e-01
8    1.388889e-01
9    1.111111e-01
10   8.333333e-02
11   5.555556e-02
12   2.777778e-02
```

and for three 6-sided dice:

```
3    4.629630e-03
4    1.388889e-02
5    2.777778e-02
6    4.629630e-02
7    6.944444e-02
8    9.722222e-02
9    1.157407e-01
10   1.250000e-01
11   1.250000e-01
12   1.157407e-01
13   9.722222e-02
14  -1.805556e-01
15  -3.703704e-01
16  -4.768519e-01
17  -5.462963e-01
18  -6.203704e-01
```

Negatives probabilities? What's wrong in the code or in the formula?

This is Valgrind report

```
==9004== 
==9004== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9004==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9004==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==9004== 
==9004== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9004== 
==9004== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9004== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You could use a debugger to find out.

Comment: fact(x-y)  -- is y ever bigger than x? Try sending in the absolute value of x-y to ensure it's always positive.

Comment: the same result

Comment: do you have an order of operations problem... `p-s*k-1`

Comment: The conditions are different for 3 die, maybe?

Comment: Grady Player, p-s*k-1 is always > p-s*k-n and C(x,y) = x!/y!(x-y)!

Comment: Curious: Why the `(float)` in `pow((float)s,n);` ?   Certainly `pow(s,n);` is sufficient - or maybe that was a debug effort.

Comment: There is no need for `pow(-1.0,k)`, a simple bit-comparison will do, e.g. `(k & 1) ? -1 : 1`.

Comment: note: the syntax for the `pow()` function is: `double pow(double x, double y);`  so it is expecting the parameters to both have type `double` but the posted code is casting one of the parameters to `float`.   Suggest changing the cast to `double`

Comment: regarding: `kmax = (p-n)/s;` on the first time through the loop this becomes `0/6`  (and during 1/2 of the loops, the result in `kmax` will be 0, so the inner loop will (usually) only be executed once!   Overall, I think the inner and outer loops need to be re-designed with the actual values in mind

Answer (score 6):

Your `C` and `fact` functions experience overflow. `fact(13)` already overflows a signed 32 bit integer.

You can use this definition for `C`, which avoids the need for `fact` entirely:

```
double C(int n, int k) {
    double r = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        r *= n - i;
        r /= i + 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This avoids large intermediate results, and accumulates the result in a double rather than an int. Using a double may not always be satisfactory, but your code is converting the result to a double anyhow, so it seems fine here.

Here's my solution to the original problem. It avoids computing powers and combinations entirely, resulting in a shorter, faster and more numerically stable solution. You can run it, for example like `./dice 3d12` to produce the probabilities of rolling 3 12-sided dice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dice_sum_probabilities(int n, int d) {
    // Compute the polynomial [(x+x^2+...+x^d)/d]^n.
    // The coefficient of x^k in the result is the
    // probability of n dice with d sides summing to k.
    int N=d*n+1;
    // p is the coefficients of a degree N-1 polynomial.
    double p[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) p[i]=i==0;
    // After k iterations of the main loop, p represents
    // the polynomial [(x+x^2+...+x^d)/d]^k
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        // S is the rolling sum of the last d coefficients.
        double S = 0;
        // This loop iterates backwards through the array
        // setting p[j+d] to (p[j]+p[j+1]+...+p[j+d-1])/d.
        // To get the ends right, j ranges over a slightly
        // larger range than the array, and care is taken to
        // not write out-of-bounds, and to treat out-of-bounds
        // reads as 0.
        for (int j=N-1;j>=-d;j--) {
            if (j>=0) S += p[j];
            if (j+d < N) {
                S -= p[j+d];
                p[j+d] = S/d;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=n; i<N; i++) {
        printf("% 4d: %.08lf\n", i, p[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int ndice, sides, ok;
    ok = argc==2 && sscanf(argv[1], "%dd%d", &ndice, &sides)==2;
    if (!ok || ndice<1 || ndice>1000 || sides<1 || sides>100) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <n>d<sides>. For example: 3d6\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    dice_sum_probabilities(ndice, sides);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In a slight variation, it appears the coefficient calculation intends integer truncation and substituting a `double` type may produce varied results. `uint64_t` provides sufficient storage for all reasonable `s` and `n` inquiries. You could do something similar to the following, which also eliminates any dependency on `pow(-1, k)` replacing the same with a simple bit-comparison detailed in the comment above.

With that in mind, and making use of exact types for portability, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int32_t power (int32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    int32_t temp;
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;

    temp = power (x, y / 2);
    if ((y % 2) == 0)
        return temp * temp;
    else
        return x * temp * temp;
}

uint64_t factorial (uint32_t v) {

    if (v <= 1)
        return 1;

    uint64_t n = 1;
    for (uint32_t i = 1; i <= v; i++)
        n *= i;

    return n;
}

int32_t coeff (uint32_t p, uint32_t n, uint32_t s)
{
    uint32_t c = 0, pn_s = (p - n)/s;

    for (uint32_t k = 0; k <= pn_s; k++)
    {
        int32_t neg1k = ((k & 1) ? -1 : 1),
            vp = (factorial (n)/(factorial (k) * factorial (n - k))) *
                (power (p - s * k - 1, n - 1))/(n - 1);

        c += neg1k * vp;
    }

    return c;
}

double ppns (uint32_t p, uint32_t n, uint32_t s)
{
    uint32_t s2n = 1;
    double invs2n;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s2n *= s;

    invs2n = (double)1.0 / s2n;

    return invs2n * coeff (p, n, s);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    uint32_t n, p, s;

    n = argc > 1 ? (uint32_t)strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 2;
    s = argc > 2 ? (uint32_t)strtoul (argv[2], NULL, 10) : 6;

    for (p = n; p <= s * n; p++) {
        double prob = ppns (p, n, s);
        printf (" points: %3" PRIu32 ", probablility: %8.4lf\n", p, prob);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dice_prob
 points:   2, probablility:   0.0278
 points:   3, probablility:   0.0556
 points:   4, probablility:   0.0833
 points:   5, probablility:   0.1111
 points:   6, probablility:   0.1389
 points:   7, probablility:   0.1667
 points:   8, probablility:   0.1389
 points:   9, probablility:   0.1111
 points:  10, probablility:   0.0833
 points:  11, probablility:   0.0556
 points:  12, probablility:   0.0278


$ ./bin/dice_prob 3
 points:   3, probablility:   0.0093
 points:   4, probablility:   0.0185
 points:   5, probablility:   0.0370
 points:   6, probablility:   0.0556
 points:   7, probablility:   0.0833
 points:   8, probablility:   0.1111
 points:   9, probablility:   0.1204
 points:  10, probablility:   0.1250
 points:  11, probablility:   0.1204
 points:  12, probablility:   0.1065
 points:  13, probablility:   0.0833
 points:  14, probablility:   0.0509
 points:  15, probablility:   0.0370
 points:  16, probablility:   0.0185
 points:  17, probablility:   0.0093
 points:  18, probablility:   0.0000
```

Comment: Sure, glad to give a different look at it, only change I would make would be to change the return of `power` (and `temp` within it) to `int64_t`, just to provide a bit of additional room for a large number of dice.

Comment: It looks like your program has some problems -- for 3 dice, the probability of rolling 3 should be the same as that of rolling 18, namely 0.0046 ~= 1/(6*6*6).

Comment: Good catch Paul, I'll look back at the wolfram docs, it will probably be the need for an *abs* or *floor*.