# Numpy: What is the probability that sum of elements in array is greater than or equal to 10?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math, probability

I am trying to write a program to calculate probability that sum of `N array elements` is greater than or equal to `M number`. Where in `N` array the first element of array is `N` while other are `N-1` (can be repeating).

For example: My array size is `N=5` and `M=10`, first element is always 5 while others from 1 to 4. So it looks like in below iteration. Since except 1st, other elements get generated randomly and I need to find probability that `Sum>=10 or not`?

```
    Random_Iteration1: Arr=[5, 3, 2, 1, 3] Sum = 13
    Random_Iteration2: Arr=[5, 1, 1, 1, 1] Sum = 9
    Random_Iteration3: Arr=[5, 1, 2, 2, 1] Sum = 11
```

I have written below code in Python:

```
    import numpy as np
    N=5 #array size
    M=10 
    arr = []
    arr.append([N])
    arr.append(np.random.choice(np.arange(1, N), size=N-1).tolist()) 
    arr = sum(arr,[]) #generates array such that 1st element is N, rest are randomly generated elements from 1 to N-1
    arr_sum = np.sum(arr) #gives array sum

    possibilities = N*N
    #numerator = I am not sure what to take here
```

I would really appreciate any help. Please let me know if any details in explanation are required.
Thank you.

Comment: do you have an algorithm worked out that you're having trouble implementing that you'd like to share with us, or are you asking us to design that algorithm?

Comment: So we're being asked to design the algorithm.

Comment: @jubins If you want help with the algorithm I'd suggest https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So you want us to design the algorithm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking for help with designing an algorithm, rather than with a coding issue.

Comment: I don't need anyone to design algorithm. I just need some help in finding the value in numerator. I am sorry if this is not the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute this exactly in O(n(m+n)) time. The problem is equivalent to finding the probability that n-1 dice, each with n-1 sides sum to at least m-n. The probability distribution for n k-sided dice is given by the coefficients of the polynomial (1+x+x^2+...+x^k)^n / k^n.

This code computes that polynomial iteratively, discarding terms corresponding to powers of x that are m or greater.

After the iteration finishes, the probabilities in the array correspond to the probability that the dice-sum is 0, 1, 2, .., m-1, whose sum is one minus the probability that the dice-sum is at least m.

The function `prob_weird_sum` is the code that computes results for your given problem.

```
from fractions import Fraction as F

# Returns the probability that the sum of
# n IID uniform random variables that take
# values 1..k is greater than or equal to m.
def prob_sum_ge(n, k, m):
    if m <= 0: return 1
    p = [F(1)] + [0] * (m - 1)
    for _ in xrange(n):
        S = 0
        for i in xrange(m-1, -k-1, -1):
            if i >= 0:
                S += p[i]
            if i + k < m:
                S -= p[i+k]
                p[i+k] = S / k
    return 1 - sum(p)

# The probability that if you add n, and n-1
# uniform IID random numbers 1..n-1, you get
# at least m.
def prob_weird_sum(n, m):
    return prob_sum_ge(n-1, n-1, m-n)

print prob_weird_sum(3, 2)
```

The output of the program is:

```
255/256
```

Comment: Another answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431205/sum-of-dices-rolls/43431658#43431658 contains very similar code for computing dice-sum probabilities that's better commented than this (although it's in C).

Comment: Thanks for helping. Does this work for any size array and threshold? So when my array size `n=10` and I want to calculate probability for `sum>=45`. It gives me 0.91 probability. But when I input `prob_weird_sum(3,2)` i.e `array=[3,1,2]` and m>=2. It should give me output as 1 but 0 is returned.

Comment: Yes, it works (now) for any size and threshold. There was previously a bug in `prob_sum_ge` that it would return 0 if m<=0 rather than 1. Fixed now.

Comment: ok, I was out trying few things. I think it works perfectly now. I was just wondering - does the array order matter here? since we are taking size of array into account, for example: if someone shuffles the array `[3,2,1]` as `[2,3,1]` and then runs the algorithm. I think the result would still remain the same but just want to confirm since we neglect 1st element which then changes to 2. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand the premise of your comment. What does it mean to shuffle the array? Your question asks for a probability which means it's an average over all possible arrays, so I don't see how to relate that to shuffling one particular array.

Comment: I got my answer. I just wanted confirm if the output remains same even if we  change order of elements within the array. For example: `[5,4,2,1,1]` is shuffled to `[1,2,1,4,5]` it will not change the output because we are taking average of all possibilities and since 5 will always be in the array, even though we withdraw it during our calculation probability still remains the same. I just wanted to confirm if I was right in thinking this way.